# R function for UV-decomposition

Tags: r, matrix-factorization

is there a function in R which performs UV-decomposition of a matrix the way it is described here (section 9.4): http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf ?

Comment: There's [funkSVD](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/recommenderlab/versions/0.2-1/topics/funkSVD) but I'm not able to make it work correctly. If you don't have missing values you can use this technique: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189730/what-is-uv-decomposition

Comment: I do have missing values. Just installed funkSVD (using devtools::install_github("mhahsler/recommenderlab") ) and will now see how it performs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried it with the example given in your pdf and the result is not the original matrix. It is closed if you increase `max_epochs` and `min_epochs`.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Yes I also tried to factorize that matrix but also realized that the performance is quiet bad. In addition, if I normalize the matrix (i.e., subtracting the row-mean) it gets even worse because for some reason all values in U and V are nonnegative even though normalized M is not..

Edit: just tried to increase min_epochs and now U and V contain negative values as well leading to good results :-)

Comment: would you care to explain a bit more? do you need a random two decomposed matrix ? as in A = B*C where you have A and you want B and C to be generated by the function ? or do you have A and B and you want C to be generated ?

Comment: @anup https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189730/what-is-uv-decomposition